# Web view is blank after watching video in full screen

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my app, i open a html page which contains a video. when i try to get back from watching video from full screen.

The Web view is disappear.

**I don't know why this happen.**

My code is as follow:

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(update:) name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerWillExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];

}
```

**it also goes into update method but webview is not shown to me.**

Comment: Webview is blank or gone ? Can you provide more details update: method etc ?